# Overall Performance improvement in WCF Restful API

Tags: performance, wcf, linq, sql-server-2008, entity-framework

We delivered a successful project a few days back and now we need to make some performance improvements in our WCF Restful API.

> The projects is using the following tools/technologies

1-  LINQ
2-  Entity Framework
3-  Enterprise library for Logging/Exception handling
4-  MS SQL 2008
5-  Deployed on IIS 7

> A few things to note

1- 10-20 queries have more than 7 table joins in LINQ

2- The current IIS has more than 10 applications deployed

3- The entity framework has around 60 tables

4- The WCF api is using HTTPS

5- All the API call return JSON responses

> The general flow is

1- WCF call is received

2- Session is checked

3- Function from BL layer is called

4- Function from DA layer is called

5- Response returned in JSON

> Currently, as per my little knowledge and research I think that the
>   following might improve performance

1- Implement caching for reference data

2- Move LINQ queries with more than 3 joins to stored procedure (and use hints maybe?)

3- Database table re-indexing

4- Use performance counters to know the problem area's

5- Move functions with more than 3 update/delete/inserts to stored procedure

> Can you point out some issue with the above improvements ? and what
>   other improvements can i do ?

Comment: 4 of your 5 improvement points are just guesses. Start with number 4 and create a new list.

Comment: I'm not sure on the linq stuff, but one thing I would recommend you do if you aren't already is check session using the global.asax methods.

Comment: @adrianm yes they are guesses as i wrote "might improve". So, kindly, suggest something if these are not correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your post is missing some background on your improvement suggestions. Are they just guesses or have you actually measured and identified them as problem areas?

There really is no substitute for proper performance monitoring and profiling to determine which area you should focus on for optimizations. Everything else is just guesswork, and although some things might be obvious, it's often the not-so-obvious things that actually improve performance.

1. Run your code through a performance profiling tool to quickly identify problem areas inside the actual application. If you don't have access to the [Visual Studio Performance Analyzer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182372.aspx) (Visual Studio Premium or Ultimate), take a look at [PerfView](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=28567) which is a pretty good memory/CPU profiler that won't cost you anything.
2. Use a tool such as [MiniProfiler](http://miniprofiler.com/) to be able to easily set up measuring points, as well as monitoring the Entity Framework execution at runtime. MiniProfiler can also be configured to save the results to a database which is handy when you don't have a UI.
3. Analyzing the generated T-SQL statements from the Entity Framework, which can be seen in MiniProfiler, should allow you to easily measure the query performance by looking at the SQL execution plans as well as fetching the [SQL IO statistics](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms184361.aspx). That should give you a good overview of what can/should be put into stored procedures and if you need any other indexes.